# Using CSS to make table rows the same height

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I'm building an app in AngularJS that gets product data and displays it on a page. The only reason I mention Angular is because, due to the way `ng-repeat` works, I can't simply put my images into one row so they default to the same height - each 'product' has to be its own `td`, `table`, `div` or similar.

Anyway, that won't make sense without explaining my code and the issues I'm having. I have products being displayed in rows of three. They look like this:

[image: Table Row Image]

As you can see, when the images are all the same height, everything works fine. The issue is, not all of my images are the same height, nor will they ever be. I'm looking for a solution that accommodates this.

**The Markup**

To avoid ugly `<table>` code I've put it all in a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qGu2V/6/

The `// spacer` images I've marked in the fiddle would (if I knew more about tables) make the `searchImgContainer` fill the height of the containing `<td>`.

**The Question**

Any ideas on how I can achieve this? The goal is not only to make all image containers the same height, but also to vertically centre the image within the container (so there is equal white space above and below it).

I know I can do this with javascript/jquery, but I'm loading hundreds and thousands of products onto a (mobile, responsive) page and I feel like constantly checking the height of the neighbouring image would create a large page load.

Is this achievable or am I stuck with Javascript solutions?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fJbTX/4/ - I am not the author. The space around the images will be a matter of margin/padding.

Comment: As noted above, this sort of thing won't work - the images are the issue, and they cannot be put into a row together. The data comes through as "products" so I get one image, one name, one price etc in a clump, this is just the way that AngularJS operates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qGu2V/7/)

```
.searchThumb{
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but the issue is that I don't know in advance the size of each image - if I set each to a static value (say 100px) then a 30px image comes along, I'm in the exact same scenario.